# Why does timestamp column value changes from presto_cli when presto server is on cloudera 6 (CDH6)?

Tags: hive, timestamp, timezone, presto, cloudera-cdh

I have an orc file created on **CDH6** cluster. There is hive table created on top of this orc file. This table is also queried from presto using presto hive connector. Presto is installed on the same CDH6 cluster. There is a time difference noticed when data is queried from presto_cli v/s hive_cli. Both hive --orcfiledump and hive query returns timestamp column value as
2021-11-08 15:09:50

```
hive> select event_time from icampaign_message_history_dm where bintime=1636383600;
OK
**2021-11-08 15:09:50**
Time taken: 0.132 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

But same data when queried by Presto_cli, timestamp column value is reduced by 5 hrs 30 mins and response is as
2021-11-08 09:39:50.000

```
presto:icampqe_cdh> select event_time from icampaign_message_history_dm where bintime=1636383600;
       event_time        
-------------------------
 2021-11-08 09:39:50.000 
(1 row)
```

Presto version 0.238,
CDH cluster timezone is GMT

Notice, when same presto binary (0.238) running on **CDH5** cluster, there is no time difference observed with hive_cli and presto_cli.

It would be great to know why the timestamp value via presto_cli is changing only on CDH6 cluster but not on CDH5 cluster when same presto version is used.

Answer (score 0):

> same data when queried by Presto_cli, timestamp column value is reduced by 5 hrs 30 mins

It seems there is an internal class that reads using IST (Indian time zone offset is UTC+05:30) and the other using UTC. Presto time semantics are largely broken. I recommend you use Trino, the fork [made by the original creators of Presto](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html).

This was a longstanding set of issues that were addressed in Trino last year but still remain in Presto. If you do test this please report the findings!